# Why does my Interceptor change the http url?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement JWT Tokens into my application. And if the user already has a JWT Token, it should be added to the http header. For this I wrote an interceptor in Angular:

**JwtInterceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Authentication } from '@core/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: Authentication) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER  } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { JwtInterceptor } from '@core/jwt-interceptor.interceptor';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
```

But now when I send requests, the API URL String becomes undefined:

```
Backend returned code 404, body was: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /undefinedreport/current</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

How did that happen? How does my API Url get changed?

For more context, the Dao.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, retry, tap, map, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { DTO } from "./dto";
import { ConfigAssetLoaderService } from './config-asset-loader.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class Dao {
  private API: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configLoader: ConfigAssetLoaderService) {
    this.API = this.configLoader.API_URL;
  }

  getReports(): Observable<DTO.Report[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<DTO.Report[]>(this.API + "report/current)
      .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleErrors));
  }
```

The configloader is not very important. Nothing changes the class whatsoever and when I remove the JwtInterceptor everything works fine.

The config loader looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigAssetLoaderService {

  public API_URL: string;
  public ENV: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public loadConfigurations() : Promise<any> {
    const promise = this.http.get('/assets/config/config.json')
    .toPromise()
    .then(data => {
      Object.assign(this, data);
      return data;
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: The interceptor seems fine so far, I am using as well so I can say. The main issue seems somewhere while apis is being hit, because you are getting a 404. Can you show configloader?

Comment: Looks like you end up with a URL the is like this: `undefinedreport/...`. See the `undefined` in there. Make sure what you're getting from `this.configLoader.API_URL` is what you expect.

Comment: @WahabShah I posted the configloader. The url is getting pulled out of a configuration.json as a promise.

Comment: i am quite sure that your `this.API` is get `undefined`. can you please check that?

Comment: did you call the `loadConfigurations` function at least once in somewhere in your app?

Comment: @yash Yes, it is called in the app.module:
`providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigAssetLoaderService) => () => configService.loadConfigurations(),
    deps: [ConfigAssetLoaderService],
    multi: true`